# Error:Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [

Tags: matlab

I am facing problem in

```
fw=D_w((IND(k,1),IND(k,2)); 
and W2(k)= ((D_w(IND(k,1),IND(k,2))/D(IND(k,1),IND(k,2))-1)*10)
```

There is a problem in the watermark extraction process and there is error in the last of the code . Any suggestions .kindly make some modifications in it .

So, we have to protect it from leaking so, they don’t reach to wrong people .We have to find the person responsible for the leakage of data . if the data  distributed to the third party found in the public domain ,it might be very serious threat to the owner of the company.

```
I=imread('girl512.bmp');
subplot(2,3,1),imshow(I,[]),title('Original Image');
wmsz=1000;
I=I(:,:,1);
[r,c]=size(I);
D=dct2(I);
D_vec=reshape(D,1,r*c);
[D_vec_srt,Idx]=sort(abs(D_vec),'descend');  
W=randn(1,wmsz);
subplot(2,3,2),plot(W),title('Watermark');
Idx2=Idx(2:wmsz+1);%choosing 1000 biggest values other than the DC
%finding associated row-column order for vector values
IND=zeros(wmsz,2);
for k=1:wmsz
    x=floor(Idx2(k)/r)+1;%associated column in the image
    y=mod(Idx2(k),r);%associated row in the image
    IND(k,1)=y;
    IND(k,2)=x;
end
D_w=D;
%WATERMARK EMBEDDING
for k=1:wmsz
    fw=D_w((IND(k,1),IND(k,2));
    fw=fw+0.1*fw.*W(k);
end
I2=idct2(D_w);%inverse DCT to produce the watermarked asset
I2_int=uint8(I2);
imwrite(I2_int,'I2_watermarkedn.bmp','bmp');
subplot(2,3,3),imshow('I2_watermarkedn.bmp'),title('Watermarked Image');

%WATERMARK EXTRACTION 
W2=[];
for k=1:wmsz
    W2(k)=((D_w(IND(k,1),IND(k,2))/D(IND(k,1),IND(k,2))-1)*10);
end
subplot(2,3,4),plot(W2),title('Extracted Watermark');
```

Comment: StackOverflow does ***NOT*** equal autocorrect for missing braces -> close.

Comment: From the FAQ: "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers (1) a specific programming problem (2,3,4) some other stuff, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" This has source code and is a specific programming problem, no matter how simplistic. SO is meant to be for _ALL_ levels of competence, even those not yet able to balance parentheses. Others may disagree, but I can't _force_ them to be right :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: The simplicity of the problem and the level of the stuff done in the code wildly disagree, rendering this is a clear cut case of "copy-paste-let-the-internet-solve-any-of-its-problems".  It doesn't show **the slightest bit of effort** on the OPs part to solve the problem, which is worth a downvote. even the MATLAB editor shows where the problem is! It is also worth a close, because this problem will not likely help anyone else in the future ("too localized").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets count them:

```
      12   3        4        opens
fw=D_w((IND(k,1),IND(k,2));
               1        23   closes
      12   3   2     3  21   cumulative
```

So, yes, they *are* unbalanced. You need to fix that. I suspect it can be fixed simply by removing one of the two initial `(` characters.

---

```
       12   3   4        5       6   7        8               opens
W2(k)= ((D_w(IND(k,1),IND(k,2))/D(IND(k,1),IND(k,2))-1)*10)
                    1        23          4        56  7   8   closes
       12   3   4   3    4   32  3   4   3    4   32  1   0   cumulative
```

Those ones *aren't* unbalanced, in terms of quantity. I can't vouch for the *placement* since it's rather complex :-)

Comment: What's difficult with the placement? You just need to verify that at every point the number on the top is not less than that on the bottom :)

Comment: @unkulunkulu, you could well have a problem with `IND(k,2))-1)` needing to be `IND(k,2)-1))`. That's what I meant, and it's totally distinct from the counts themselves. Both those follow the rules in terms of what you've mentioned but will have drastically different results.

Comment: %WATERMARK EXTRACTION
W2=[];
for k=1:wmsz
    W2(k)=((D_w(IND(k,1),IND(k,2))/D(IND(k,1),IND(k,2))-1)*10);
end
subplot(2,3,4),plot(W2),title('Extracted Watermark');

Comment: can u see any problem with the above block

Comment: @user2281636, that's better asked as a new _question_ rather than in a comment. First, you'll be able to format it better, second it'll reach an audience greater than just me :-)

Comment: ok ...but if you can solve this then pls help me out !!